# MAX31855 K type thermocouple being affected by power supply and motor

Tags: power-supply, arduino, esp32, max31865

I have an ESP32 that has 3 MAX31855 sensors measuring 3 temperatures. All temperatures are reading excellent when connecting only the computer USB to the ESP32 module, but when I plug my external  AC-DC 12V 8A 100W Switching Power Supply  (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000846764734.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.27424c4db1lms9) the temperatures get lower values.

From the 12 DC volts that I get from the power supply I then have a 12vDC to 5vDC converter:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003515877710.html?spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.27424c4db1lms9

And I use this 5v to power my ESP32. **The MAX31855 sensors are powered from 3.3v from the same ESP32.**

These are the values from the 3 sensors when only USB power is connected.

`<<<<< Receive Data:`

`Bytes received: Request Type: Request Temp Data`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 0 in C = 20.81`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 0 in C = 18.25`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 1 in C = 20.50`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 1 in C = 17.25`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 2 in C = 20.69`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 2 in C = 19.00`

​

When I plug the power supply then I get these values:

`<<<<< Receive Data:`

`Bytes received: Request Type: Request Temp Data`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 0 in C = 20.81`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 0 in C = 16.75`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 1 in C = 20.50`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 1 in C = 15.25`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 2 in C = 20.69`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 2 in C = 14.50`

​

And when I turn on the 12V motor connected to the same circuit then I get these values:

`<<<<< Receive Data:`

`Bytes received: Request Type: Request Temp Data`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 0 in C = 20.81`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 0 in C = 9.25`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 1 in C = 20.50`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 1 in C = 7.00`

`Internal temperature of Thermalcouple 2 in C = 20.75`

`Temperature of Thermalcouple 2 in C = 11.50`

​

What is very interesting is that the Internal MAX31855 temperature is never affected, the only one affected is by the K Type thermocouple temperature probe.

Any clue and any recommendations on what things to do in order to avoid this annoying situation?

Appreciate it.

Comment: I don’t have oscilloscope but just bought this one 1,208.50 MXN$  49％ Off | FNIRSI-1C15 Professional Digital Oscilloscope 500MS/s Sampling Rate 110MHz Analog Bandwidth Support Waveform Storage
https://a.aliexpress.com/_mPJbK9q will take 3 weeks to arrive and hope this let me see more clearly if there is noise or something wrong

Comment: Why would you choose to buy your equipment from mali-express (or pee-bay or shamazon or bang-bad) when there is no datasheet, no guarantee of performance, a likelihood of poor design and reliability, probably no recognized adherence to safety and no adherence to any quality system. Why?

Comment: Ups, maybe because ignorance and is cheap but you are right. Maybe that won’t give me the right data I need. Anyway is on its way 

Comment: @Andyaka pee-bay made my day. Regarding OP's question... `hope this let me see more clearly if there is noise or something wrong` it's obvious that there's noise. However, your circuit might need some improvements as well since the design and layout affect the performance.

Comment: I will try to do a schematic and update this ticket to see if someone can help me with this head pain

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve it amazingly and easly and cheap. I bought an oscilloscope that haven't received yet but by experimental I added a 0.01uf between the leads of the thermocouple and now it works without any issue. Also now the 3 thermocouples readings are exactly the same. Before I had like 0.50 C difference between each one and now is perfect.